# Field History in Visualforce Email Template

Tags: apex, visualforce, aura, visualforce-component, developer

Hi I am trying to use Field History for custom Object Work_Order__c in visualforce email template .
I am facing error :  **Invalid field Work_Order__c__History for SObject Work_Order__c**
Could someone help me to understand what is causing the error?
Thanks in Advance!

```
 <messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Work_Order__c">
    <messaging:HtmlEmailBody>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!relatedTo.Job_Name_Text__c != NULL}">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Job Name: "/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!relatedTo.Job_Name_Text__c}">
                <font style="color:{!IF(relatedTo.Work_Order__c__History[0].OldValue.Job_Name_Text__c != relatedTo.Work_Order__c__History[0].NewValue.Job_Name_Text__c, 'red', 'black')}">
                    {!IF(relatedTo.Work_Order__c__History[0].OldValue.Job_Name_Text__c != relatedTo.Work_Order__c__History[0].NewValue.Job_Name_Text__c, ' (changed from ' + relatedTo.Work_Order__c__History[0].OldValue.Job_Name_Text__c + ' to ' + relatedTo.Work_Order__c__History[0].NewValue.Job_Name_Text__c + ')', '')}
                </font>
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </messaging:HtmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: this might help https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000095wwIAA

Comment: Hi @AmanPatil, I would like to know how to use the histories in the email template without using an apex class

Comment: did you enable history tracking for the field ?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled and the History data old and new value is shown in UI. But I cannot use the values in email template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship name between a custom object and its field history is named `Histories`

Thus,

```
relatedTo.Work_Order__c__History[0]
```

should be

```
relatedTo.Histories[0]
```

Here's a screen shot from Workbench of a custom object in my org called `Recollect_Detail__c`, you can see the child relationship defined

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Documents](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5)

> Salesforce stores an object’s tracked field history in an associated object called StandardObjectNameHistory or CustomObjectName__History. For example, AccountHistory represents the history of changes to the values of an Account record’s fields. Similarly, MyCustomObject__History tracks field history for the MyCustomObject__c custom object.

Your should Use `Work_Order__History` instead of `Work_Order__c__History`

Comment: I used Work_Order__History  as well , But I am facing the same problem Invalid field Work_Order__History for SObject Work_Order__c

Comment: have you queried for `Work_Order__History ` and are you able to see values for `oldValue.Job_Name_Text__c` and `NewValue.Job_Name_Text__c`

Comment: @Sanjana the error message says that `Invalid field Work_Order__History for SObject Work_Order__c` that means its trying to find a field named as `Work_Order__History` in  `Work_Order__c` and that is incorrect, your relatedToType should be `Work_Order__History` if you want to access `oldValue.Job_Name_Text__c and NewValue.Job_Name_Text__c `